# How to use setMessageReaction(Telegram Bot API)?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Telegram recently added a new API function to set reactions:

> #### [`setMessageReaction`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmessagereaction)
>
> Use this method to change the chosen reactions on a message
> ...

---

I've created a bot, added it to the channel as an administrator, and now I want to add a reaction to the publication on its behalf.

---

I've tried the following PHP code:

```
function sendToTelegram($token, $method, $response)
{
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $token . '/' . $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $response);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
}

$result = sendToTelegram('BOT_KEY', 'setMessageReaction', ['chat_id' => -1001493310237, 'message_id' => 27, 'reaction[]' => ""]);
```

In the response I'm getting:

```json
{"ok":true,"result":true}
```

But the publication doesn’t get a reaction.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passing the emoji as the wrong data format.

##### The `reaction` parameter of [`setMessageReaction`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmessagereaction) needs to be an array of [`ReactionType`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#reactiontype).

So instead off passing `""` as a reaction, you'll need something like:

```php
[
    [ 'type' => 'emoji', 'emoji' => '' ]
]
```

---

I've used the following PHP code to succesfully set a Reaction:

```php
<?php


$token = '859163076:....';
$chat = 1;
$message = 2;

$data = http_build_query([
    'chat_id' => $chat,
    'message_id' => $message
]);

$reactions = json_encode([
    [ 'type' => 'emoji', 'emoji' => '' ]
]);

$re = @file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/setMessageReaction?{$data}&reaction={$reactions}");
var_dump($re);
```

[image]